# Fixing encoding in python

Tags: python, php

I sent a json from php to python and the turkish strings has an encoding/decoding problem. 
This is an example string from php:

> Güvenlik amaçlarına giriş

I use this line of code to execute python:

```
$output = shell_exec("python receive_data.py " . base64_encode(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)) . " 2>&1");
```

I print the data in python with this:

```
print(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
```

And this is how it looks:

> G\xc3\xbcvenlik ama\xc3\xa7lar\xc4\xb1na giri\xc5\x9f

I don't have much knowledge on encoding/decoding. I made sure the php end was completely utf-8 and windows was also using utf-8. Changed the project encoding to utf-8 on PyCharm as well.

Edit:

Complete data array from php:

```
array (size=15)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Güvenlik amaçlarına giriş' (length=29)
      'en' => string 'Introduction to Security Goals.' (length=31)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Kriptografinin Matematiği.' (length=27)
      'en' => string 'Mathematics of Cryptography.' (length=28)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Geleneksel Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifreler.' (length=41)
      'en' => string 'Traditional Symmetric Key Ciphers.' (length=34)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Cebirsel Yapılar.' (length=18)
      'en' => string 'Algebraic Structures.' (length=21)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Modern Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifrelere Giriş.' (length=45)
      'en' => string 'Introduction to Modern Symmetric Key Ciphers.' (length=45)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Gelişmiş Şifreleme Standardı.' (length=33)
      'en' => string 'Advanced Encryption Standard.' (length=29)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Modern Simetrik Anahtarlı Şifrelerle Şifreleme.' (length=50)
      'en' => string 'Encipherment Using Modern Symmetric-Key Ciphers.' (length=48)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Stream Ciphers' (length=14)
      'en' => string 'Akan Şifreleme Yöntemleri.' (length=28)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Ara Sınav' (length=10)
      'en' => string 'Midterm Exam' (length=12)
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Doğrusal ve Diferansiyel Kriptanaliz.' (length=38)
      'en' => string 'Linear and DifferentialCryptanalysis.' (length=37)
  10 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Kriptografik Özet Fonsiyonları.' (length=33)
      'en' => string 'Cryptographic Hash Functions.' (length=29)
  11 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Asimetrik Kriptoloji' (length=20)
      'en' => string 'Asymmetric Cryptography' (length=23)
  12 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Protokollar, Tcp/Ip Protokol ve Hizmetlerinde Güvenlik' (length=55)
      'en' => string 'Protocols, Security in Tcp/Ip Networks' (length=38)
  13 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Güvenlik Duvarları ve Sanal Özel Ağlar' (length=42)
      'en' => string 'Firewall and Virtual Private Networking' (length=39)
  14 => 
    array (size=2)
      'tr' => string 'Saldırı Tespit Sistemleri' (length=27)
      'en' => string 'Intrusion Detection Systems' (length=27)
```

Comment: you did: `[utf-8 enc] -> [b64 enc] -> [b64 dec]` now you just need `[utf-8 dec]`

Answer (score 2):

`base64.b64decode()` [returns bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode).

Decoding those bytes will give you the original string:

```
import base64

b64 = base64.b64encode('Güvenlik amaçlarına giriş'.encode('utf8'))
print(b64)
# b'R8O8dmVubGlrIGFtYcOnbGFyxLFuYSBnaXJpxZ8

b = base64.b64decode(b64)
print(b)
# b'G\xc3\xbcvenlik ama\xc3\xa7lar\xc4\xb1na giri\xc5\x9f'

s = b.decode('utf8')
print(s)
# Güvenlik amaçlarına giriş
```

Comment: I get this error when I decode: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 24: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Are you still using Python2?

Comment: I am using 3.7.

Comment: Hmm...Do you get that error from the above code snippet?

Comment: The snippet works but decoding my complete data gives the error. I edited my question with the complete array I'm sending. I thought some characters might be causing the problem.